# How do I replace absolute times ("1:30 PM") with relative times ("15 minutes ago") and have them automatically update?

Tags: javascript, facebook, date, time, calendar

Is there a Javascript script to change the time and date of blogs automaticly like facebook ???

for example "10 minutes ago" instead of "May 15 2010 12:30".

-Thank You

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the **[`timeago`](http://timeago.yarp.com/)** jQuery plugin; it's a popular way to handle this situation. It will also do the updating for you, if you like, and it supports micro-formatted goodness.

In a nutshell, it turns all `abbr` elements with an **[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** timestamp into fuzzy timestamps. Thus, if you have

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2015-01-10T15:00:00Z">January 10, 2015</abbr>
```

and the current time is 15:30Z on January 10, 2015, you'll get something like:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2015-01-10T15:00:00Z">30 minutes ago</abbr>
```

as a result.